# Error: Could not find or load main class maven project

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, find, program-entry-point

I have been facing a problem since 2 weeks and I'm getting desperate about solving it as it seems to appear in every new project I make. I have created a new maven project, the java_home variable and the path are set properly with my newly installed java directory, I've cleaned the project with maven clean, there is no apparent error and everything seems fine, but when I run the main class, I get this error telling me Could not find or load main class without any other details. 
It would be really great if you could help me out, thank you in advance.
to provide more info, here is the structure of my project

[image]

and here is the code of my main class, I'm using hibernate as well

[image]

The User_ class is here

[image]

Finally here are some screen caps in case you need them

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How are you running the main class? If you do `mvn clean` (on the commandline?), do you also refresh in eclipse?

Comment: I tried refreshing and I also did the maven clean on eclipse not on the commandline :(

Comment: That's ok. If you run from eclipse, then just open the main class in the editor, click the `v` on the green `>` play button, and select Run As... Once you've done that, just clicking the play / run button will run it.

Comment: that's exactly how  I tried to run it before :( but it didn't work. it still doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Open your pom.xml file and check if the main class is set in the below element

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>full.path.to.Class</mainClass>
```

Comment: actually the pluging element is not specified in the pom :( I added the pom.xml file in the question above if you need to see it

Comment: I added the pluging tag and the full path th the class and it still doesn't work